SQL func on py lang, return columns
I need some help, I don`t have enough knowledge.
My question is, how can I make a select from function without writing every column like in example, and is there any solution to write only short select which will return all columns ?
I have a function in SQL which was written on py lang, it returns data ('array') and number of columns ('shape'), it could be from 2 to 10 or more columns.
To execute data from func I am using this type of select
example:
select 
    cast(jsonb_array_elements(test_00.test_func('array')::jsonb)->>0 as text) as column1,
    cast(jsonb_array_elements(test_00.test_func('array')::jsonb)->>1 as text) as column2,
    cast(jsonb_array_elements(test_00.test_func('array')::jsonb)->>2 as text) as column3,
    cast(jsonb_array_elements(test_00.test_func('array')::jsonb)->>3 as text) as column4,
    cast(jsonb_array_elements(test_00.test_func('array')::jsonb)->>4 as text) as column5,
    cast(jsonb_array_elements(test_00.test_func('array')::jsonb)->>5 as text) as column6,
    cast(jsonb_array_elements(test_00.test_func('array')::jsonb)->>6 as text) as column7;

I though that my func returns number of columns so, I can write a variable for select or something in this way, but I don`t know how to realize it, hope someone will help
i tried to write with generate series but a rewrite my function and i know exact number of columns, just need to write it in select, to return number of columns
select test_00.test_func('shape');
maybe it can help
WITH numbers AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM generate_series(0, (select test_00.test_func('shape')::int - 1)) as cnt
)
select 
    jsonb_array_elements(test_00.test_func('array')::jsonb) ->> cnt
from numbers;

i want to make something like this but this code returns every column in 1, I want to separate it to different columns

You want this as a stored procedure/function in the database or as a python function that connects via a DB-API client?

lets try like a procedure/function, in the database
